# How to understand $\Phi: \operatorname{Hom}(V, W)\rightarrow W$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am new to linear algebra and I have the difficulty to understand how a linear transformation can be viewed as an element from a space that maps to another element in another space. For example, I encountered a question that requires me to show $\Phi: \operatorname{Hom}(V, W)\rightarrow W$ is a linear transformation, where $V$ and $W$ are finite dimensional vector spaces. However, I don't know how this can be true and specifically how to define such a function so that it could be linear. Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to show that a specific function $\Phi$ is a linear transformation, or find an example of $\Phi$ which is?

Comment: Probably $v \in V$ is fixed a priori and OP means $\Phi(T) = T(v)$. Then showing that $\Phi(T+\lambda S) = \Phi(T)+\lambda \Phi(S)$ is a one line computation.

Comment: You need to understand why the Hom is vector space in the first place.

Comment: @oscarmetal Your question is confusing. It would be best if you could copy the question that you encountered exactly as it is written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can essentially think of Linear maps as matrices. Say we have two finite dimensional vector spaces $\mathbb{R}^n\text{ and }\mathbb{R}^m$ and a matrix $A$ of dimension $m\times n$. Elements in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are vectors of dimension $n\times 1$, let such an element be $u$. So now if we multiply the matrix $A$ with $u$ we get an element $v$. Which is:
$$A.u=v$$

Now, the dimension of $v$ is $m\times 1$, which is an element of $\mathbb{R}^m$. So our matrix A acted on an element $u\in \mathbb{R}^n$ to produce an element $v$ in $\mathbb{R}^m$. Check that if a matrix satisfies all the properties of linearity.

Then consider all such matrices between $\mathbb{R}^n \text{ and } \mathbb{R}^m$ as elements of a vector space. Check if they satisfy all the properties of a vector space.

This is not an answer, but I think this example will help you in getting started.

Comment: This is exactly what I am wanting for. An example which can help me  to understand. I am sorry for that I can't post the exact question because it is from an ongoing assignment. However what I can say is that it is about finding  the dimension of the subspace $\{l\in\operatorname{Hom}(V, W): l(v)=0\}$. I want to show this is the kernel of the linear transformation that I said in the question, so that I can exploit the dimension theorem.